# Python subclass a class variable has is being treated as a classmethod

Tags: python-3.x

Using python310, I am running across something unexpected (but i guess normal behavior).  I am looking for an explanation of the pythonic design decision.

I am trying to make subclasses of a class with slightly custom behavior as specified in cls.METHOD

However, when METHOD is called, it is autopassed in cls. essentially it is treated as a @classmethod.  (see below)

I understand I can pass in some_function as a instance variable and call it in self.run().  My main question is *why* METHOD, when being called, is a @classmethod

```
def some_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print("Why are any args being filled at all?!??!!")

class A(object):
    METHOD = None

    def run(self):
        self.METHOD()
        
        
class B(A):
    METHOD = some_function

# Create an instance and call the run method
instance_of_b = B()
instance_of_b.run()
```

Output:

```
(<__main__.B object at 0x7f532970f340>,) {}  
Why are any args being filled at all?!??!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that it's being treated as a class method is wrong; `<__main__.B object at 0x7f532970f340>` is an *instance*, **not** the class, which would be `<class '__main__.B'>`.

Methods are instance methods *by default* and need `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` to deviate from that default. `*args` will start with the instance for instance methods, the class for class methods, or neither for static methods. Because you did not use either decorator, it's being treated as an instance method and you could say "autopassed" the instance.

Although I'd say this pattern doesn't look particularly ingratiating, a more fleshed out example to demonstrate these differences would be; (swap `B`'s `METHOD` and see what each function's output looks like.)

```py
def some_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)

@staticmethod
def some_static_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)

def some_instance_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self, args, kwargs)

@classmethod
def some_class_function(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print(cls, args, kwargs)

class A(object):
    METHOD = None
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.METHOD(*args, **kwargs)
        
class B(A):
    METHOD = some_function

# Demo
instance_of_b = B()
instance_of_b.run("arg",kwarg="kwarg")
```

You'll get;

1. `some_function`

```
(<__main__.B object at 0x000002ED9340C190>, 'arg') {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}
```

2. `some_static_function`

```
('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}
```

3. `some_instance_function`

```
<__main__.B object at 0x0000021F3E07C190> ('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}
```

4. `some_class_function`

```
<class '__main__.B'> ('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}
```

A final consideration is the tongue-twist of taking all this into account and having to use the instance method format for `run` itself. Note that if you made it a class method, then `some_instance_function` would stop working. It must be an instance method to allow `METHOD` to interpret the `self` calling it according to how `METHOD` wants to interpret it. With `run` being an instance method, `METHOD` is free to do what it wants with the calling `self`.

On the other hand, the name `self` is convention; any name can be used for the first argument. If the meta of using `self` in `run` is confusing, you can call it something else, i.e. the following works the same.

```py
class A(object):
    METHOD = None
    def run(caller, *args, **kwargs):
        caller.METHOD(*args, **kwargs)
```